# Is this Possible to give String data type as Number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can i give string data type as Number
For example

```
var a = "abc" 
//Some Code
console.log(typeof a)  //number
```

I want to play with "typeof"  i want to print string as a number
WITHOUT  changing it to number

Comment: No, you can't. A string is a string, not a number.

Comment: Are you really trying to test if the string contains something that could be parsed as a number?

Comment: What would you do with that ability if it *were* possible? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't provide any means of overriding the `typeof` operator, so you can't do that.

In fact, JavaScript doesn't have operator overloading at all (and is *extremely* unlikely ever to get it). There are a couple of games you can play with `toString` and `valueOf` on object instances, but they don't really provide overloading, and don't relate to `typeof` (and your string is a primitive string, not an object, so...).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't effectively overload `typeof` (or any of the other JavaScript operators) like that. If an expression is a string, its `typeof` will always give you `string`. If an expression is a number, its `typeof` will always give you `number`. There's no way to change that.

(You can create objects with `new Number` and `new String`, which will then give you `object` instead, but those constructors should never be used, because then you'll have objects, not primitives, which will behave in unexpected ways)